# How to use list comprehension and put 1 for every time there a string contains a word

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with different info about arrests.

```
arrests_df["is_violent"] = [
    1 if x == "Battery" or x == "Assault" else 0 for x in arrests_df["statute_desc"]
]
```

So in the column called "statute_desc", every time the word battery or assault is mentioned, put 1. But this code doesn't work.

Comment: What about the code doesn't work?

Comment: It just puts "0" every time in the new column, even when the original row contains the word "Battery" or "Assault". The row contains a bunch of words. So it'll be like "Third-Degree Assault". That might help

Comment: Based on the above you want `"Battery" in x or "Assault" in x`.  `==` is not a containment operator

Comment: Please provide sample data, your expected outcome, and the actual outcome.  As is, this is not a *[minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)*

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment:

You want `"Battery" in x or "Assault" in x`. `==` is not a containment operator.

```
'a' == 'abc'  # False
'a' in 'abc'  # True
```

Likewise:

```
"Third-Degree Assault" == 'Assault'   # False
'Assault' in "Third-Degree Assault"  # True
```

and thus:

```
>>> data = ["Third-Degree Assault", "Assault", "Foobar"]
>>> [1 if x == "Battery" or x == "Assault" else 0 for x in data]
[0, 1, 0]
>>> [1 if "Battery" in x or "Assault" in x else 0 for x in data]
[1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: can you write the whole line of code? Cause I get this error: 
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: You should check your data then, is it possible that `"statute_desc"` contains floats instead of strings?

Comment: i get TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: That's what you said the first time.  Try using `collections.Counter(map(type, arrests_df["statute_desc"]))`.  That being said, it seems like this question was closed (as a duplicate of a mostly unrelated question).

Comment: Yeah I don't know why they closed it. And I get "name 'collections' is not defined" now. Thank you for your help though, even though the question is closed.

Comment: I have blanks in the column, does that affect anything?

Comment: you have to run `import collections`